# mailgun stripping out inline formatting of html

Tags: html, mailgun

I have a fairly large amount of formatted HTML to send out as an email, and I'm using cURL to the mailgun API to test it. Mailgun sends the HTML mail just fine as long as there's no inline formatting (i.e. remove the style element from the below), but the second I introduce some, it strips out any quotes, and stops at the first semi-colon. Do I need to escape some of these characters, and how do I do that?

```html
curl -s --user 'api:key-xx' \
    https://api.mailgun.net/v3/sandbox6ca85c222ca740ee9f3d36436e7e8516.mailgun.org/messages \
    -F from='Testy <postmaster@sandbox6ca85c222ca740ee9f3d36436e7e8516.mailgun.org>' \
    -F to='myaddress@example.com' \
    -F subject='Hello again' \
    --form-string html='<html><body>
<p style='font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;font-size:10.0pt'>some text</p>
</body>
</html>'
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape the quotes in the following way:

```
--form-string html='<html><body><p style=\'font-family:\"Calibri\",sans-serif;font-size:10.0pt\'>some text</p></body></html>'
```

Comment: Thanks, but that results in this error:   -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'

Comment: you need to put the parameter in one line .. let me update the code

Comment: Another error:
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `<'
This seriously has to go on one line? I have a full page of HTML code - hmm, looks like mailgun isn't the solution, if that's the case.

Comment: I've just checked, and the **--form-string** parameter doesn't need to be on one line. It worked perfectly well over a few lines, just as long as I didn't have any formatting in it.